# How do I add a string to a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have to make a dictionary that will turn this list:

```
locations = [ 
  ['Lorraine Izaguirre', 'MA'], 
  ['Chris Clements', 'PA'], 
  ['Kari Bacon', 'PA'], 
  ['Chris Clements', 'NY'],
  ['Chris Clements', 'NJ'],
  ['Jamee Cheek', 'PA'],
  ['Kari Bacon', 'NY']
]
```

into:

```
{'Lorraine Izaguirre': ['MA'], 'Chris Clements': ['PA', 'NY', 'NJ'], 'Kari Bacon': ['PA', 'NY'], 'Jamee Cheek': ['PA']}
```

This is the code I have already made, but for some reason I keep getting an error saying that I can't append a string to a list. I am very confused, because I thought I was explicitly stating that `state` is a 1x1 list in the append statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def organize(locations):
  name_dict = {}
  for i in range(len(locations)-1):
    name = locations[i][0]
    state = locations[i][1]
    if name not in name_dict:
      name_dict.update({name:state})
    else:
      name_dict[name] = name_dict[name].append([state])
  return name_dict
```

Edit: Solved it, there were a couple issues

1.) pointed out below that I needed to change `name_dict.update({name:state})` into `name_dict.update({name:[state]})`

2.) I needed to change `range(len(locations)-1)` into `range(len(locations))`

and 3.) change `name_dict[name].append([state])` into `name_dict[name].append(state)`

Comment: `I thought I was explicitly stating that state is a 1x1 list in the append statement` In the case where you're adding `name` for the first time, you're using `name_dict.update({name:state})`, and `state` is just a plain string.  Perhaps you meant `name_dict.update({name:[state]})` instead?

Comment: Also, `.append()` doesn't return anything; it modifies the list in-place.  So you don't want `name_dict[name] = name_dict[name].append([state])` -- you just want `name_dict[name].append([state])`

Comment: That works, all I needed to do was change it to ```name_dict.update({name:[state]})``` also I made the adjustment to the append statement just to see if maybe something was bugging out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict.setdefault` for the task:

```
locations = [
    ["Lorraine Izaguirre", "MA"],
    ["Chris Clements", "PA"],
    ["Kari Bacon", "PA"],
    ["Chris Clements", "NY"],
    ["Chris Clements", "NJ"],
    ["Jamee Cheek", "PA"],
    ["Kari Bacon", "NY"],
]

out = {}
for l, abbr in locations:
    out.setdefault(l, []).append(abbr)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Lorraine Izaguirre': ['MA'], 'Chris Clements': ['PA', 'NY', 'NJ'], 'Kari Bacon': ['PA', 'NY'], 'Jamee Cheek': ['PA']}
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.defaultdict` has been designed for this

```
from collections import defaultdict

def organize(locations):
    name_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for name, state in locations:
        name_dict[name].append(state)
  
    return name_dict
```